# Vue how to add click event to <nuxt-img>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my `vue`-app I need to make a `<nuxt-img />`-clickable, so I tried to do this:

```html
<nuxt-img :src="image.src" @click="isClickable ? doSomeStuff : null" />
```

but for some reason I don't know, this is not working - nothing happens on click.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try this inline handler `@click="()=>isClickable ? doSomeStuff() : null"` or  `@click.native="()=>isClickable ? doSomeStuff() : null"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Yes, the `native`-thing did the trick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the `native` modifier :

```js
@click.native="isClickable ? doSomeStuff : null"
```

Answer (score 2):

I would pass a function there, like somebody already suggested in the comments:

```
@click="() => isClickable ? doSomeStuff : null"
```

but better would be to enclose the logic in a method and call the method
@click="handleClick"

```
...
methods: {
  handleClick(){
    if(this.isClickable){ this.doSomeStuff() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<nuxt-img :src="image.src" @click="isClickable ? doSomeStuff : null" />
```

**doSomeStuff** has to be defined as a function in order to be called like that

Otherwise you should call it with a [thunk](https://reactgo.com/thunks-javascript/#:%7E:text=A%20thunk%20is%20just%20a,Example%20of%20synchronous%20thunk)

For instance:

```html
<nuxt-img :src="image.src" @click="isClickable ? () => doSomeStuff : null" />
```

Still I would give an undefined to the @onclick event instead of a null value

```html
<nuxt-img :src="image.src" @click="isClickable ? () => doSomeStuff : undefined" />
```